# Is $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x,y$ are even an Equivalence relation?

Tags: equivalence-relations

The following instruction defineds an Equivalence relation on the set of natural numbers.

$x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x,y$ are even

My idea:

Reflexivity: $x \sim x \Leftrightarrow x,x$ is even

Symmetry:  $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x,y$ are even

Transitivity: $x \sim y \Leftrightarrow x,y$ are even, $y \sim z \Leftrightarrow y,z$ are even $\Rightarrow x \sim z \Leftrightarrow x,z$ are even

So my result is, that it is an Equivalence relation, but the solution says it is not, but doesn't say why. Where is my mistake?

Comment: An element should always be equivalent to itself. As you remarked $x\sim x \Leftrightarrow x$ is even, so this is not an equivalence relation as it is not reflexive for uneven numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflexivity means that no equivalence class is empty, since the equivalence class of an element $x$ always contains at least one element: $x$ itself. As Marc pointed out in his comment, reflexivity fails, indeed if $x$ is odd then the set of $y$ such that $x \sim y$ is empty, thus $\sim$ is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: A consequence of fact that reflexivity fails is that we cannot speak of an equivalence relation. Then there are no equivalence classes so expressions like 'the equivalence class of $x$ is empty' make no sense.

Comment: @drhab thanks, edited

Answer (score 1):

According to the question the relation is defined on $\Bbb N$ in which case reflexivity does not work.

If $\mathscr R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $A$ then $\mathscr R$ is a reflexive relation iff $a \mathscr aR \;\; \forall a \in A$. I'm sure according to the definition of the relation above in your exercise the relation is not reflexive since it would not work *for every* element in the given set. If my assumption is correct your counter example is $1 \not \sim 1$ and hence this is not an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

For the reflexivity: is $(1,1)$ an element of the relation?

Answer (score 0):

If $\sim=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}\mid x\; and\; y\; even\right\} $
then $\left(1,1\right)\notin\sim$ showing that $\sim$ is not reflexive.